# Pygame Level Editor

Tags: python, pygame

I'm currently making a platformer in pygame and this is a small editor I built through tutorials and endless searching. The thing is, everything is fine but I am searching for a way to save the rect color each time and then save it and export it like the other properties, I want each rect to have its color saved and not like how it works now and changes the colors of all the rects included in to_draw. I'd be happy if you helped, thanks!

```
import pygame
from colors import *
pygame.init()
file = open('levels/level.txt', 'w')
size = width, height = 1280,960
window = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption( "platformer editor v0.02" )

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 60

to_draw = []
current_color = 0
draw_start = False

##GRAMMATA##
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
def show_text(msg,color,x,y):
    text = font.render(msg,True,color)
    textpos = (x,y)
    window.blit(text,textpos)
############


running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            mouse_pos = mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = mouse_pos
            draw_start = True

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            final_pos = mouse_pos
            draw_start = False

            rect = pygame.Rect(pos,(final_pos[0]- pos[0], final_pos[1]-pos[1]))
            rect.normalize()
            to_draw += [rect]

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                current_color += 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                current_color -= 1

            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                for platform in to_draw:

                    print("["+str(platform).split("(")[1].split(")")[0] +",black ],")
                    file.write("["+str(platform).split("(")[1].split(")")[0] +",black ]\n")
            if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                to_draw.pop()
    window.fill(white)

    if current_color not in [0,1,2,3,4]:
        current_color = 0

    if draw_start:
        pygame.draw.rect(window,red, pygame.Rect(pos, (mouse_pos[0] - pos[0],mouse_pos[1]- pos[1])))
    for item in to_draw:
        pygame.draw.rect(window,color_list[current_color],item)


    show_text("x:",red, 1070,0)
    show_text(str(mouse_x),red,1100,0)
    show_text("y:",red,1170,0)
    show_text(str(mouse_y),red,1200,0)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(fps)

file.close()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test that code but it should work. I'm using tuples to store the values

```
import pygame
from colors import *
pygame.init()
file = open('levels/level.txt', 'w')
size = width, height = 1280,960
window = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption( "platformer editor v0.02" )
strong text
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 60

to_draw = []
current_color = 0
draw_start = False

##GRAMMATA##
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
def show_text(msg,color,x,y):
    text = font.render(msg,True,color)
    textpos = (x,y)
    window.blit(text,textpos)
############


running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            mouse_pos = mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = mouse_pos
            draw_start = True

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            final_pos = mouse_pos
            draw_start = False
            rect = pygame.Rect(pos,(final_pos[0]- pos[0], final_pos[1]-pos[1]))
            rect.normalize()
            to_draw += [(rect, Color('red')] #specify color

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                current_color += 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                current_color -= 1

            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                for platform, color in to_draw:
                    s = "[{},{}]".format(platform, color)
                    print(s)
                    file.write(s)
            if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                to_draw.pop()
    window.fill(white)

    if current_color not in [0,1,2,3,4]:
        current_color = 0

    if draw_start:
        pygame.draw.rect(window,red, pygame.Rect(pos, (mouse_pos[0] - pos[0],mouse_pos[1]- pos[1])))
    for item, color in to_draw:
        pygame.draw.rect(window,color,item)


    show_text("x:",red, 1070,0)
    show_text(str(mouse_x),red,1100,0)
    show_text("y:",red,1170,0)
    show_text(str(mouse_y),red,1200,0)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(fps)

file.close()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks you really saved me, halped me alot!